# Is it true that custom HTTP headers can be used to prevent CSRF because the browser prevents sites from sending custom HTTP headers to another site?

Tags: http, security, http-headers, csrf

I was studying CSRF today and I found the following sentence:

> custom HTTP headers can be used to prevent CSRF because the browser
> prevents sites from sending custom HTTP headers to another site but
> allows sites to send custom HTTP headers to themselves

Inside this article: https://www.invicti.com/web-vulnerability-scanner/vulnerabilities/cross-site-request-forgery-in-login-form-invicti/

Can someone explain this concept better to me and tell me if the sentence is correct?

Can I assume that if I send a CSRF token inside a custom HTTP header the attacker can't do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain this concept better to me and tell me if the sentence is correct?

The sentence is correct in so far as modern browsers that implement the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will refuse to make requests that are initiated by a foreign ("cross-origin") web page and that go beyond what a simple click on a hyperlink or submission of an HTML form could achieve. For example, they refuse such requests if they contain the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header. This can be used as a defence against CSRF if the server accepts only requests with such a `X-Requested-With` header (or another non-standard header). Then it can be sure that they have not been made from a different origin (that is, from a "foreign web page").

However, such cross-origin requests are still made if the server uses the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS) protocol and declares the foreign web page trustworthy (through an `Access-Control-Allow-*` header in a [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) response).

But CSRF tokens are still needed for "simple" requests, such as ones initiated by submitting an HTML form. These requests cannot contain non-standard headers and must therefore transfer the CSRF token in a (hidden) form field.

> Can I assume that if I send a CSRF token inside a custom HTTP header the attacker can't do it?

See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74413172/16462950).