# A variation of 'Double Submit Cookies' to prevent CSRF attacks

Tags: javascript, csrf

Can CSRF attacks be effectively prevented by following this simple approach:

1. Generate a UUID at the front end itself for EVERY request
2. Send this UUID via a cookie and request header to the backend.
3. Backend will compare both the received UUIDs.
4. If they match, it's a legit request otherwise it isn't.

The thought process behing this is:

1. A naive attacker doesn't know that we are setting a request header for every request
2. Even if the attacker figures it out from the transpiled js files, his webpage won't have access to the cookie so that it can read the value in the cookie and set the header
3. And I don't think, he can even set a fresh cookie for the vulnerable website

So would the above approach be effective in mitigating CSRF or my understanding/approach is completely wrong?

Comment: By setting a special header, your request becomes a non-simple request, and such requests are already protected by the CORS protocol (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74833191/is-it-true-that-custom-http-headers-can-be-used-to-prevent-csrf-because-the-brow)). It would even suffice to demand the header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Ok so since the browser prevents sites from sending custom HTTP headers to another site, the attacker's website won't be able to send the custom header that my website's frontend is sending. And at the backend, all I have to do is to check if the custom header is present in the request to validate the request. Is my understanding correct? Is this enough to prevent CSRF?

Comment: Correct, as explained in the linked question.

Comment: Your original idea is a known and in many cases, acceptable solution to prevent csrf. The one proposed in comments above (custom header) is not, and will be weak against some attacks that might or might not be actual threats in your case. This is definitely not the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

The mere presence of a custom header offers protection against CSRF for clients that implement the CORS protocol, as explained in [Is it true that custom HTTP headers can be used to prevent CSRF because the browser prevents sites from sending custom HTTP headers to another site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74833191/is-it-true-that-custom-http-headers-can-be-used-to-prevent-csrf-because-the-brow).

Additional protection for clients (old browsers, perhaps?) that might not implement CORS properly is offered by your idea: Even if malicious code on a different site could make a request with a custom header in it, it could not set this header to the value of a cookie, because the cookie is not available to Javascript code running on a different site.

This reasoning is what you also say in #2 and #3. But since #1 relies on the attacker not knowing something, it does not offer real security (only "security by obscurity").