# Is CSRF protection require or not for API with strict CORS config?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, csrf

I have an Angular app with calls to Spring Boot. The CORS policy allowing only Angular to send requests.

```
cors.setAllowedOrigins  only "example.com:4200"
```

CSRF attacker trick the user to perform unwanted action, but to bypass CORS, script cannot be in attacker site, isn't? So, we are in attacker inject script (XSS), XSS means the CSRF token will be sent anyway. Also, auth token not send via cockie, so attacker will have to use script that
will trigger out code to include the access token.

CSRF can happen or we are implementing CSRF "just for fun"?

Comment: *Also, auth token not send via cockie* Why? The session token is send with cookie. What kind of authentication do you use?

Comment: Yes because, contrary to frustratingly popular belief, [CORS is no defence](https://twitter.com/annevk/status/948831079649169408).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74833191/is-it-true-that-custom-http-headers-can-be-used-to-prevent-csrf-because-the-brow

Comment: @jub0bs They didn't read the specifiation, they didn't know the full name: Cross-origin resource sharing. OP apparently didn't do it, too. *but to bypass CORS* makes no sense, because CORS isn't a defense, it is a way to open the same-site policy for some origins. They also try to disable CORS and wonder that it doesn't work.

Comment: @dur JWT and it is not in cockie, which CSRF when logged, the request will be without the token.

Comment: @jub0bs  II tgink you are right, but in my case CSRF on not logged in is on risk, attacker will send registration request with the user audit fields oppps! this will consume the user rate limit. But I don't think logged in user is affected as the access token won't be added unless the attacker trgigger http client call (only case when access token is send).

Comment: @dur Not sure if I need to specify this, but I was responding to the OP, not to your comment. 

Comment: @jub0bs I know. No offense. I just want to extend your comment with my experience.

Comment: @dur No problem. I wasn't sure to whom your comment was directed. All good.