Spring security CSRF integration: question about the mobile application documentation example
I don't understand the CSRF integration for mobile application presented in Spring Security documentation.
It is proposed to provide a GET /csrf endpoint for the client to get a CSRF token and reuse it when an unsafe request is made to the server.
I don't understand how this is securing against CSRF attack. Can't a malicious site obtain a new token from this endpoint before submitting a request to the server?

No, it cannot, because of the same-origin policy (see the remark about CORS protocol in this answer).

@HeikoTheißen thank you for your answer. However, if CORS protection is enabled on server side the malicious website cannot send a POST request neither, am I thinking right?

Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74833191/is-it-true-that-custom-http-headers-can-be-used-to-prevent-csrf-because-the-brow

Thanks for this piece of information. Actually, as you mentioned in your previous post, even with CORS enabled, a malicious website could still send HTML 4.0 "simple request" that does not need preflight request.

That's why you need CSRF in the absence of non-standard headers.
