# Should CSRF protection token be given before authenticating?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, csrf

I want to add csrf protection by sending the csrf token , i used the csurf library in node/express JS i tried getting the token with a get request and it gives me the token successfully , but i guess the token should be provided after the authentication but the problem is when i try to login/signup it doesnt let me , and say `invalid csrf token` since they are `POSTS` requests , Any ideas how solve that ?

I can get the token with a get request before authentication and it works but it doesnt seem like a secure way !

**app.js**

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3001", credentials: true }));
app.options("*", cors());

//middleware

//this one is to make our backend server understand/recognize the JSON format
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//cookies parser
app.use(cookieParser());

const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: true,
});
app.use(csrfProtection);

// const csrfProtect = csrf({ cookie: true });

//this one is see the requests that are coming from the backend
app.use(morgan("tiny"));

app.use("/public/uploads", express.static(__dirname + "/public/uploads"));
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const api = process.env.API_URL;

//routers
app.use(`${api}/auth`, authRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/user`, userRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/searching`, searchingRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/chat`, chatRoutes);
```

**REGISTER/LOGIN CONTROLLER**

```
const register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;

    //checking if user exists
    const userExists = await User.exists({ email });
    if (userExists) {
      return res
        .status(409)
        .json({ success: false, message: "E-mail already in use." });
    }
    //encrypting password
    const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    //creating the user after crypting the password
    let user = new User({
      username,
      email: email.toLowerCase(),
      password: encryptedPassword,
    });
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        userId: user._id,
        email: user.email,
      },
      process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
      {
        expiresIn: "24H",
      }
    );
    user = await user.save();
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      user: {
        email: user.email,
        username,
        token,
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Error occurred with the server , Please Try again",
      error,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a security problem with issuing a CSRF protection token *before* authentication. Indeed, the logon request itself may already [deserve CSRF protection](https://labs.detectify.com/2017/03/15/loginlogout-csrf-time-to-reconsider/).

As discussed in [CSRF Tokens vs Session Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412651/csrf-tokens-vs-session-cookies), the CSRF token must be bound to an HttpOnly cookie, but the argument given in the answer to that question remains valid even if that cookie is not a session cookie (which would be issued after authentication) but a special "CSRF protection cookie" issued together with the CSRF token (which could both be issued when the logon page is loaded). This cookie would reach its end of purpose after the CSRF-protected request has been successfully made.

Such a "CSRF protection cookie" can also be used in order to protect requests that are not authenticated by a session cookie but, for example, by a client certificate.