# Am I doing CSRF right?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I'm making a website that's business in the front, but all Django in the back. Django is what concerns me.

Each request asks for a CSRF token. Actually, two tokens. One is set automatically by a cookie, and another has to be provided as a POST argument.

So I have an API endpoint that sends a token. Then I use that token to make other requests.

But this feels like having a guard who won't let you in without a password, but will gladly tell you the password if you ask him for it. Whom does this help?

EDIT: I hope it's not too embarrassing, I'm new to these tools.

Django:

```
def initialize(request):
    """
    Queried by the front end when the page first loads.
    Sends back csrf_token, which is needed by all POST requests (this one uses GET), and user name associated with the
    current request - that is, the user that's logged in.
    """
    data = dict()
    data['csrf_token'] = get_token(request)
    data['logged_in_user_name'] = auth.get_user(request).get_username()
    
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

React/Redux:

```
var csrfToken = null as null | string; 

/**
 * This function fetches the CSRF token that is necessary for POST requests from the server.
 * Also gets the logged-in user name and adds it to the state.
 * 
 * @param dispatch A function that updates the store by dispatching an action.
 */
export async function initializeCsrf(dispatch: Dispatch)
{
    if (csrfToken)
    {
        return csrfToken;
    }
    
    try
    {
        const response = await fetch(`${Ernots.APIURLPrefix}initialize`,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include',
        });

        var json = await response.json();
        csrfToken = json.csrf_token;
        
        dispatch(loginActions.setLoggedInUserName(json.logged_in_user_name));
        dispatch(requestActions.setBackendUnreachable(false));        
        return csrfToken;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        dispatch(requestActions.setBackendUnreachable(true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add example with code your question seems too generic and confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I was AFK when I posted. (Also, I thought the post didn't go through, so I didn't worry about it.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the protection offered by a password to a CSRF protection token.

- A password protects the *server* against requests from unknown clients that it does not want to *serve*. This protection would be gone if everyone could ask for the password.
- CSRF protection protects the *client* against requests that it does not want to *make* or, in other words, against being lured to a malicious website that triggers requests without the user being aware of it. Telling the token to the client upon request does not weaken this protection, because the client must co-operate and is thus aware of the request it is going to make.

Comment: I store the token in a way that should only be visible in its module. But if there is another, evil script running on the page, it could just query my API, obtain a token, and then do evil stuff. That doesn't protect anyone from anything.

Comment: An evil script can run on your page only if it is vulnarable to cross-site scripting. If that is true (which I cannot judge based on the information you have given), CSRF protection cannot help against that.

Comment: Then what can it protect from?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74413172/16462950