# Bypass token-based CSRF protection by simply mimicing the user workflow

Tags: cookies, csrf, csrf-token

Imagine there is a `bank.com` website and it uses a [double-submit CSRF protection method](https://kylebebak.github.io/post/csrf-protection):

#### Normal user story:

After logging in through the `bank.com/login` endpoint (where a session cookie and a CSRF cookie is set), the user will send a GET request to `bank.com/transfer_form` (which includes the session cookie) to get a form which has a hidden element with the CSRF token. Now, the user can send a POST request to `bank.com/transfer?to=Bob&amount=1000&CSRF=XXXX` to transfer some money to their friend.

#### How we are protected from CSRF attacks

Now, imagine if the user goes to `evil.com`. I understand that this website will not be about to send a POST request to `bank.com/transfer?to=Hacker&amount=100000&CSRF=XXXX` because `evil.com` doesn't know the value of the CSRF token, so we have protection against CSRF.

#### How I think we can still bypass this CSRF-protection

I don't understand what is stopping the following workflow:

1. User goes to `evil.com`
2. `evil.com` will use the user's browser to send a AJAX GET request to `bank.com/transfer_form` to get the CSRF token.
3. `evil.com` uses the CSRF token from step 2 to send the POST request to `bank.com/transfer?to=Hacker&amount=100000&CSRF=XXXX`.

I don't understand what is stopping the `evil.com` to fully mimic the user flow and bypass any token-based CSRF-protection method. With this weird logic, I seemed to have convinced myself that any token-based CSRF-protection method is useless, and the only thing that is stopping the above flow is the `SameSite` cookie attribute (and maybe the CORS policy). Is this correct?

Comment: `evil.com` can make the request in step #2, but it cannot read the response and hence cannot get the CSRF token. Therefore, it cannot make the request in step #3. See also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412651/csrf-tokens-vs-session-cookies).

Comment: Thank you for the link. [The link you sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412651/csrf-tokens-vs-session-cookies) does confirm that CORS policy is really the main protection against this CSRF attack. So it goes back to my question that the token-based CSRF-protection seems to be useless: Because if you have set the CORS policy, you are protected from CSRF and if you don't set the CORS policy, the CSRF token is basically useless, and can be bypassed by mimicing the user workflow. Basically, the double-submit CSRF token didn't add any extra protection!

Comment: Or maybe there is a special case where the CORS policy alone can't stop `evil.com` from sending a request to `bank.com/transfer?to=Hacker&amount=100000` (without CORS) ? Maybe if this URL is in a img tag on `evil.com` (or some other special case), the browser will actually send this request and your money will be stolen even if the CORS policy is set?

Comment: CORS protects against _non-simple_ cross-origin requests, so it is sufficient if the server insists on non-simple requests (for example, by demanding an `X-Requested-With` header). Requests made by `<img>` elements are simple requests.

Comment: CORS prevents non-simple cross-origin requests from being _made_, and the _responses_ to any cross-origin requests from being _read_.

Comment: Wow I get it. Thank you!