# Does CSRF protection work when the client and server are hosted on different servers?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, csrf

I am currently in the development phase of my project, where the client (react) is hosted at localhost:3000, and the server (laravel) is hosted at localhost:8000. I'm implementing CSRF protection, and I'm curious about its effectiveness in a setup where the client and server are on separate servers and I'm using PAT token-based authentication instead of a session-based.

Do CSRF tokens work effectively in such scenario?

If they do, what steps should I take to ensure CSRF protection functions properly in my specific setup?

I appreciate any insights or guidance!

Comment: I'm using SANCTUM for SPA. It's secure way to connect two Laravel sites that are located on different servers. It's necessary to configure cors.php and sanctum.php (both are inside 'config' directory) depends on your needs and domain names that you are using.

Comment: CSRF works in the same way, whether the protected requests are same-origin or cross-origin. In the cross-origin case, you have to make sure that cookies are included in the requests ([`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen to what cookies are you referring? XSRF-TOKEN Cookie? If that's the case, is having an XSRF-TOKEN cookie stored in our browser safe? since this is a stateless app, so the attacker can have access to both PAT and XSRF-Token and thus sending an authorized request from a cross-origin site. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am referring to any cookies to which the CSRF protection token might be [bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412651/csrf-tokens-vs-session-cookies).